# How to identify app user to save records in external SQL database for that user

Tags: sql, flutter, dart, userid, user-identification

I have a flutter app that stores everything locally.
I want to change that and store data in one SQL database stored in a server.
I need to know how to identify the user so I can identify the data stored for each user.
A user might have the app installed on different devices so I want to make sure he can acccess his data in the SQL server from any of his devices.

Comment: look for REST Api